# How to change a word in a file based on the previous line?

Tags: python

So, basically there's this txt file I want to change.

```
qreg i[1];
qreg j[1];
qreg k[1];
qreg l[1];
qreg m[1];
qreg n[1];
qreg ancilla0[1];
qreg ancilla1[1];

cx m[0],ancilla0[0];
cx ancilla0[0],m[0];
cx m[0],ancilla1[0];
```

Here are some examples of the lines it contains.

The output should be -

```
qreg i[1];
qreg j[1];
qreg k[1];
qreg l[1];
qreg m[1];
qreg n[1];
qreg o[1];
qreg p[1];

cx m[0],o[0];
cx o[0],m[0];
cx m[0],p[0];
```

It should change the ancilla word into a letter based on the previous line, in alphabetical order. (if the line before qreg ancilla is qreg c, qreg ancilla should change into qreg d)
How can this be done?

Comment: This isn't remotely well enough specified to write code, and any reasonable interpretation of the task makes it enormous, far beyond the scope of a single Stack Overflow Q&A. Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum** - we can't just vaguely explain the relevant techniques in broad strokes, and we also cannot write a solution for this, which might well run hundreds of lines of code and rely on third-party libraries. Even if we could, it would require a **vastly** more precise specification.

Comment: Suitable question scope for Stack Overflow looks like "how do I read a file line by line?", or "how do I examine a string like `'qreg ancilla1[1];'` and decompose it into `['qreg', 'ancilla', '[1]', ';']`?" or "how do I remember a mapping between `ancilla1` and `p` and use it to replace text later in the program?". (You should be able to look up existing Q&As for some of these.) But then you would still need to apply a lot of logical rules, which means first **determining what those rules are**. There are **countless** inputs I could think of where it isn't clear what the result should be.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']


with open('testStorage.txt', 'r') as fp:
    data = fp.readlines()


start = alphabet.index(data[0][5:-5])
end = False
for i in range(len(data)):
    try:
        if alphabet[i+start] == data[i][5] and end != True:
            print('yes')
        elif data[i] != '\n' and end != True:
            print('else')
            toReplace = data[i][5:-5]
            data[i]= data[i].replace(toReplace, alphabet[i+start])
    except:
        end = True


with open('testStorage.txt', 'w+') as file:
    file.writelines(data)
```

The code above finds the incorrect ones and then replaces it with the next item in the inventory.